# Interview for masters program including two minute scientific presentation

Tags: masters, presentation, interview

Yesterday I received an email that I have to give a two minute scientific presentation as part of an interview for a masters program on this coming Monday. Now I am really struggling whether I have to include scientific data in my presentation or that I can explain a concept. My time is very limited. The email just states: "You are requested to give a 2 minutes (max. 7 slides) scientific presentation about a topic of your own choice". What do you advise me to do?

Comment: My advice would be not to use 7 slides in a 2 minute talk.

Comment: Good lord, my current rate is 1 slide every 30 minutes!

Comment: @DanielR.Collins Then I'd have to say that you have way too much information on each slide!

Comment: @DanielR.Collins Well, your use case is obviously not suitable for the OP either. I'll delete my comments, if you delete your "db-y" one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much that you can explain in two minutes; therefore, the key is to choose a topic that you can do justice to in such a short time. Choose a topic that you are interested in and confident about. Additionally, make sure that the topic is relevant to the course you are applying for. Create an interesting PowerPoint presentation of 4-5 slides. Check out some short scientific presentations online to get some ideas.

Comment: Short scientific presentations are about 10-15 minutes :'). I feel like I have to pitch now. Thank you for the tips!

Comment: I think in 2 minutes you could pull off a mini-review. Define: a topic, one exploratory direction within that topic, 1-2 recent efforts (papers) in that exploration, a question that still remains, and a way to tackle that question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all congratulations on receiving an interview for a master's program. As part of your application, "you are requested to give a 2 minute presentation about a topic of your own choice." Since your question is quite broad "What do you guys advice me to do?", the best answer possible is to stick to the fundamentals of a good speech and be sure to give a relevant presentation in a clear and concise manner. This is only one step in the application process, so do not overthink it too much.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! It is an interview via Skype-call, making it even harder to get the message across